# Better than lib "highlight-symbol"

Tags: highlight-chars

windows 10, emacs 26.1.

To highlight symbol I use package `highlight-symbol`

```
http://nschum.de/src/emacs/highlight-symbol/
```

Nice.

But I need symbol "=" to be a separator.

[image]
As you can see the `test=this` is highlight. But I don't like this. I need to highlight only word `test`. Of course I can press <kbd>SPC</kbd> between `test` and `=`. But it not comfortable. Suppose I have 100 symbols `=`.

Same result in `text-mode`:

[image]

Has any alternative for this package? Better that this package.

Comment: Better in what way?  Is there a problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: No problem with current package  "highlight-symbol" . But I want try something else to compare. Maybe found smt better features than in package "highlight-symbol".

Comment: @Drew I need symbol "=" to be a separator. I update my post

Comment: `=` is a symbol-constituent character in the syntax table used by `lisp-interaction-mode` (which is what the `*scratch*` buffer is using).  In other modes it might not be a symbol character (in `c-mode` it is a punctuation character, for example).  I'm not sure why you would be writing `test=this` in elisp code, but I wouldn't particularly recommend changing the elisp syntax table.  In other modes it might be more reasonable to customize syntax entries, if desired.  So, *what kind of text* is this?  For which mode(s) do you want this behaviour?

Comment: test=this not in elisp code. It maybe in any buffer. E.g. shell mode. In log files and so on.

Comment: The point is that "symbol" can mean different things in different buffers, so the *specific* major modes you're interested in is important to the question.  Your screenshot is of a buffer in `lisp-interaction-mode`, so that *is* an elisp buffer (and `test=this` is a valid elisp symbol).

Comment: @phils Not help. I get same result is text mode. I updated my post.

Comment: You can temporarily change the syntax of `=` with the following advice (put it into your init file and restart Emacs): `(defun my-highlight-symbol-ad (oldfun &rest args)  
  "Call 'highlight-symbol' with modified syntax table."  
  (interactive)  
  (let ((orig (char-syntax ?=)))  
    (unwind-protect  
 (progn  
   (modify-syntax-entry ?= ".")  
   (apply oldfun args))  
      (modify-syntax-entry ?= (string orig)))))  
  
(advice-add 'highlight-symbol :around #'my-highlight-symbol-ad)`

Comment: @Tobias I get error message after call "my-highlight-symbol-ad" - funcall-interactively: Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (oldfun &rest args) "Call 'highlight-symbol' with modified syntax table." (interactive) (let ((orig (char-syntax 61))) (unwind-protect (progn (modify-syntax-entry 61 ".") (apply oldfun args)) (modify-syntax-entry 61 (string orig))))), 0

Comment: No don't call `my-highlight-symbol-ad` directly! Use `highlight-symbol` as usual after executing the `advice-add`. The advice modifies the behavior of `highlight-symbol`.

Comment: I was fooled by my customizations. The code above does only highlight the free-standing occurrences of the symbol. and not that ones in `symbol=symbol`. It is because font lock uses symbol boundaries to identify the symbols and `=` has still symbol-syntax in `fundamental-mode`. You could change the syntax of `=` permanently if you like. But it may be that that has other unwanted consequences.

Comment: You can try [msearch.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/msearch) There you can just search for the mouse selection without boundaries. Therefore, if you select `foo` with the mouse it will also highlight `foo` in `foobar`. You can also set the search string boundaries to word. So `foo` in `foobar` will not be highlighted but `foo` in `foo_bar` will. You can freeze the current highlighting. Meaning that `foo` will still be highlighted even if you select `bar`. `bar` will be highlighted with another color in that case.

Answer (score 3):

First of all note that the behavior of `highlight-symbol` in your first example is actually right. The `*scratch*` buffer is in `lisp-interaction-mode`. The contents of the buffer is supposed to be Elisp and `test=this` is a symbol in Elisp. For an instance the following is a legal Elisp form and you can eval it in the `*scratch*`-buffer:

```el
(setq test=this t)
```

Phil stated this clearly in [his comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46307/better-than-lib-highlight-symbol#comment71279_46307).

Symbols are built from characters with word syntax and symbol syntax.
The syntax is stored in the syntax table of a buffer and usually comes with the `major-mode` of the buffer.

An example of a major mode where `=` does not have symbol syntax but punctuation syntax is `c-mode`.
If you put your buffer into `c-mode` with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `c-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> the command `highlight-symbol` works as you want it to work. If point is in `test` of the string `test=this` only `test` is highlighted and not the full string `test=this`.

You made your second attempt with `text-mode`. What syntax does `=` have in `text-mode`? Does it end a sentence? No actually not. Is it a symbol. Yeah that fits better. So `=` ended up with symbol syntax in text mode. That has the effect that `test=this` is interpreted as one symbol in text mode.
But, that is a rather weak decision. If you like you can change the syntax of `=` in text mode with the following hook:

```el
(defun my-=-is-punctuation ()
  "Give ?= punctuation syntax."
  (modify-syntax-entry ?= "."))

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook #'my-=-is-punctuation)
```

If you activate `text-mode` in a buffer after installing that hook you get the wanted behavior of `highlight-symbol` there.

Changing the syntax table of some established major mode as personal customization is a quite drastic measure. It may be that some syntax based features of that mode do not work anymore afterwards.

Alternatively you can advise `highlight-symbol` a bit to fit your purpose.
We can just temporarily modify the syntax table when calling `highlight-syntax` and we can modify `highlight-syntax-border-pattern` such that also the equal sign `=` counts as a border.
If we do not like that the equal sign is also highlighted we need to exclude it from the regexp group to be highlighted. Therefore it is important to know that `font-lock-add-keywords` allows to identify the regexp group to be highlighted.
In `highlight-symbol-add-symbol-with-face` the regexp group to be highlighted is hard-coded as 0 -- the full regexp. We want to replace it with 1 -- the group excluding the potentially present equal signs.
Because its hard-coded we need an `:override` advice for `highlight-symbol-add-symbol-with-face`. That is a pity since such an `:override` advice does not follow development changes in `highlight-symbol-add-symbol-with-face`. At least it works with `highlight-symbol-20160102.2009`.

As long as [`highlight-symbol-add-symbol-with-face`](https://github.com/nschum/highlight-symbol.el/blob/7a789c779648c55b16e43278e51be5898c121b3a/highlight-symbol.el#L273) does not change you can use the following code in your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).
(It is likely that it is possible to adapt the advice of `highlight-symbol-add-symbol-with-face` if it changes.)

Install the Elisp code restart Emacs and call `highlight-symbol` as you are used to. It will no longer interpret `test=this` as one symbol but as two symbols separated by a punctuation.

```el
(defun my-highlight-symbol-ad (oldfun &rest args)
  "Call 'highlight-symbol' with modified syntax table."
  (let ((orig (char-syntax ?=)))
    (unwind-protect
    (progn
      (modify-syntax-entry ?= ".")
      (apply oldfun args))
      (modify-syntax-entry ?= (string orig)))))

(advice-add 'highlight-symbol :around #'my-highlight-symbol-ad)

(defun my-highlight-symbol-add-symbol-with-face-ad (symbol face)
  "Put SYMBOL with FACE into `font-lock-keywords'.
Do it like `highlight-symbol-add-symbol-with-face' does
but use regexp group 1 instead of 0.
Note that after installing that advice you need to
use a group in `highlight-symbol-border-pattern'.
The original setting of `highlight-symbol-border-pattern'
without groups does not work anymore."
  (let ((keywords `(,symbol 1 ',face prepend)))
    (push keywords highlight-symbol-keyword-alist)
    (font-lock-add-keywords nil (list keywords) 'append)
    (highlight-symbol-flush)))

(advice-add 'highlight-symbol-add-symbol-with-face :override #'my-highlight-symbol-add-symbol-with-face-ad)

(setq highlight-symbol-border-pattern '("\\(?:=\\|\\_<\\)\\(" . "\\)\\(?:\\_>\\|=\\)"))
```